# Android Twilio OnHold VOIP

Tags: android, twilio, twilio-twiml

I have my VIOP call in action and the suddenly I get GSM call or something else so I need to put VOIP call on hold.

I found this https://www.twilio.com/blog/2009/09/call-queueing-putting-callers-on-hold-calll-redirect-new-url-new-feature.html

So now I thinks that I need to use `twiml` to place caller on hold

```
<Response>
<Say> Thank you for calling, a representative will be with you shortly</Say>
<Play loop="100">mymp3link</Play>
</Response>
```

And afterwards taking caller off hold with:

```
POST https://api.twilio.com/2008-08-01/Account/{YourAccountSid}/Calls/{WaitingCallersCallSid}
CurrentUrl=http://www.example.com/dial-representitive
```

But the main question is if this requests could help with my issue?

And if it can help how can I use my Android client to send this `twiml` request?? (with twilio library or with common HTTP request??)

P.S. Seems need Twilio evangelist here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio Documentarian here - will help if I can :)

For the initial use case you are describing (you are on a VoIP call with another party, and then receive a call that requires you to put the call on hold), I will suggest a path of least resistance, and we can iterate from there.

In the TwiML to initiate the call from the Android client, rather than using `<Dial>` to dial a number, consider creating a two-person [`<Conference>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference). Then if your Android client needs to jump off the conference call, they can simply rejoin the same conference call in progress once their non-VoIP call has ended.